# mySQL query killed the server

Tags: mysql, cpu-usage

I am trying to find duplicate entries on a column so they can be fixed in preparation for creating a unique index on that column.  The database currently has around 4.5mil records.

The query I used was:

```
SELECT `sig`, COUNT(*) c FROM `info` GROUP BY `sig` HAVING c > 1;
```

This immediately locked me out of the server and the remote admin had to reboot it to restore function.  My question is, is there another better option for finding duplicates?  Some other way to mitigate the effect of the query?

Comment: Just a thought...can you make a non-unique index on the column first?

Comment: If that query forced you to reboot your server... I don't think the problem is your query...

Comment: Agreed.  This does sound a lot like a hardware issue.  An SQL query can not take down a whole otherwise-stable server, period.  At best it could kill mysqld, but even that requires something else be broken already.

Comment: ok, I just did the query and saw the CPU spike and die.  I'll ask the web host to look into it.  On my local copy of the database executing the query also crashed database manager.

Comment: Yes, I could make a non-unique index.  I can see where that might help, however, on my local copy I have a non-unique index and it still crashed the database manager.

Comment: It is a table.  It won't let me post such a short answer so I am typing this useless sentence.